# Why doesn't light pass through all objects?

Tags: optics, visible-light

In Rutherford's gold foil experiment, nearly all alpha particle penetrated the gold foil except a few which were deflected by large angles. Since photons are also particles which are considerably smaller than alpha particles, does that mean they also passed through the foil and the foil was transparent?

Assuming photons are point sized I would expect them to pass undeflected and unabsorbed through almost every material, no matter how thick the layer of atoms is. But of course that is not the case since only a selected materials are transparent. Why isn't everything transparent? What stops the photons from passing through?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Apart from any other technical issues, what makes you think that, "photons are also particles which are considerably smaller than alpha particles"?  The size of a photon wave packet cannot be smaller than its wavelength, which (for visible light) is thousands of times larger than an *atom*, much less a nuclear like an $\alpha$-particle

Answer (score 2):

The gold foil in the famous Rutherford scattering experiment was very thin - only a few atoms thick. So it would have been transparent to light. The surprising result was not that most alpha particles passed through it with little or no deflection, but that a few alpha particle were deflected by large amounts.

A thin enough slice of any material is transparent to light. As the thickness increases, it becomes more likely that a photon (or a passing alpha particle) will interact with an atom, and most materials cease to be transparent.

Comment: Photons will mostly interact with the electrons, not the nuclei (unless they are x-rays or gammas). The alphas are also interacting with electrons, leading to energy loss but no large-angle scattering.

Comment: But space in atom is empty then most of them must not interact with electron